# creating a package from .ipynb files in colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am refactoring my colab project to create packages.  Currently, my "package" is an ipynb file that I call each of the projects

```
all_files = ["helpers/timer", 
             "helpers/beeper", 
             "helpers/fileHelper",

             "api_interaction/fetcher", 
             "api_interaction/spider",
              
             "analyzers/attributeAnalyzer",
             "analyzers/midiAnalyzer"  
            ]
for file in all_files:
  %run "{file}.ipynb"
```

I tried putting an `__init__.py` file inside each of the subfolders, but couldn't quite work out how to run an ipynb file from a py file.

Ideally would like to be able to call `import project.helpers`, `import project.api_interaction`, etc.  Is there a way to do this in colab?

Comment: you could just export the notebook files as .py with the same name.

Comment: woohoo!  !jupyter nbconvert --to python ./helpers/timer.ipynb does exactly the trick to get the .py files

Answer (score 1):

idea from @thorntonc

```
import os

folders = ["helpers", "api_interaction", "analyzers"]

for folder in folders:
  for obj in os.listdir(folder):
    if obj.split(".")[-1] == "ipynb":
      py = f"{folder}/{obj}"
      print(f"Running {py}")
      os.system(f"jupyter nbconvert --to python {py}")
```